# How do I make soft caramel for homemade Caramel Apples?

Tags: candy, caramel

I am making Caramel apples using, brown sugar, butter, vanilla, and condensed milk. The caramel is coming out very thick and sticky to the extreme.  How can I make a nice caramel that is not hard to bite into?

Comment: Lower the temp you are cooking, you shouldn't be exceeding the softball stage. If you don't have a candy thermometer, you can check this with a glass of ice water. After cooking for 15 minutes, spoon out some caramel and drop the spoon in the ice water. The moment you can roll the caramel into a goopy ball (doesn't have to be perfect, just that you CAN shape it somewhat) then it's just reaches softball stage. If not, wait 5 more minutes and try again with a fresh spoon.

Comment: I am using a thermometer and taking caramel off at 230 degrees..soft ball stage.  but it has a sugar daddy consistency --what can i add to make it lighter or not so sticky

Comment: Try my method, it doesnt use temp it uses behavior as an indicator.

Comment: So, how'd it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

*Yield: Approximately 1½ cups*

**Ingredients**

***Making Caramel - Method 1 (Wet Method)***

1 cups (200 grams) granulated sugar

¼ cup (60 ml) water

***Making Caramel - Method 2 (Dry Method)***

1 cup (200 grams) granulated sugar

**For the Caramel Sauce:**

*Caramel*

¾ cup (178 ml) heavy whipping cream

2 tablespoons (28 grams) unsalted butter

½-1 teaspoon salt

1 teaspoon vanilla extract

1 vanilla bean, seeds removed from the pod (optional)

2 tablespoons whiskey (optional)
**

```
**Instructions**
```

**

**Making Caramel - Method 1 (Wet Method):**

Combine sugar and water in a medium saucepan over medium heat. Allow sugar to melt and bring to a boil. Let the mixture caramelize and wait for it to turn dark amber in color. Do not stir, swirl pan as needed to promote even caramelization.

**Making Caramel - Method 2 (Dry Method):**

Sprinkle sugar evenly on the bottom of a medium saucepan set over medium heat. Allow sugar to melt and caramelize, swirling as necessary to promote even caramelization. Do not stir.

**To make the Caramel Sauce:**

As soon as the caramel is dark amber in color, immediately remove it from the heat and slowly add the heavy cream while whisking constantly. Caramel will bubble violently.

Return mixture to medium heat and simmer until any clumps have dissolved and 
mixture is smooth.

Remove from heat and stir in butter and salt. Add vanilla extract and if desired, vanilla bean and whiskey.

Comment: Your sauce uses as much cream as sugar! (And the name already calls it a sauce). Are you sure it is thick enough for caramel apples? I would expect it to be way too runny.